# How to calculate the mode for each value in another column in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, window-functions

I have a table like this:

```
ID   Group  Gender
------------------
1    A      M
2    A      M
3    A      F
4    A      M
5    A      U
6    B      F
7    B      F
8    B      M
9    C      U
10   C      F
11   C      U
```

I am trying to calculate the **mode group** for each gender. In other words, for each gender, tell me which is the most popular group.  So the results I want would be as follows:

```
Gender  ModeGroup
-----------------
M       A          (because 3 males in group A, 1 in B and 0 in C)
F       B          (because 2 females in group B, 1 in A and 1 in C)
U       C          (because 2 unknown in group C, 0 in B and 1 in C)
```

In the case of a tie, I need a record returned for each of the tied groups.

How can I do this elegantly in TSQL?  I think I need to use a window function, but I've  been struggling with how to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Declare @t Table(Id Int Identity, [Group] Varchar(1),Gender Varchar(1))
    Insert Into @t Values
    ('A','M'),('A','M'),('A','F'),('A','M'),('A','U'),
    ('B','F'),('B','F'),('B','M'),
    ('C','U'),('C','F'),('C','U')

;With Cte As 
(
    Select 
        [Group]
        ,Gender
        ,GenderCount = Count(Gender)
    From @t
    Group By [Group],Gender
)

Select Gender,ModeGroup = [Group]
From (
        Select 
            *,
        Rn = Dense_Rank() Over(Partition by [Group] order by [Group],GenderCount desc)
        from Cte
     )X
Where Rn =1
```

**Result**

```
Gender  ModeGroup
M       A
F       B
U       C
```

Comment: This one works when you dont have ties, but that means that you didnt answered the question.

Comment: It could work with ties if you `select distinct` and use `RANK()` in the inner query. But I dont know if that is a good solution.

Comment: @Johan , modified..it handles both now

Comment: Accepting this one because it was the easiest to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Here's my No-CTE solution:

```
SELECT
  Gender,
  [Group]
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      [Group],
      Gender,
      RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Gender ORDER BY [Count] DESC) AS [Rank]
    FROM
      (
        SELECT [Group], Gender, SUM(1) AS [Count]
        FROM GroupGender
        GROUP BY [Group], Gender
      ) AS counts
  ) AS ranks
WHERE
  [Rank] = 1
```

SQL Fiddle Demos: [No ties](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ace11/9/0) and [With ties](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6628f/1/0)

UPDATED: (see comments)

Comment: +1 Nice work. Seems to work correct in both cases. Even if you have more three genders tied.

Comment: Thanks, but your answer returns mode gender for each group, instead of the mode group for each gender. If you change PARTITION BY [Group] to PARTITION BY [Gender] then it works.

Answer (score 1):

use Common Table Expression,

```
WITH results
AS
(
    SELECT  Gender, 
            [GROUP], 
            COUNT(*) totalCount,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY Gender ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) a
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY Gender, [GROUP]
)
SELECT Gender, [GROUP]
FROM RESULTs
WHERE a = 1
-- ORDER BY [GROUP]
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36504/12)

Comment: -1 Not working correctly. Used your demo and changed the indata so group `A` and `B` should both be `F`. But thats not the case. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bd277/1

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
;WITH Vals AS (
        SELECT  Gender,
                [Group],
                COUNT([Group]) Cnt
        FROM    Table1
        GROUP BY Gender,
                [Group]
)
, ValsID AS (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Gender ORDER BY Cnt DESC) RowID
        FROM    Vals
)
SELECT  Gender,
        [Group]
FROM    ValsID
WHERE   RowID = 1
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36504/9/0)

Comment: this can be simplified further.

Comment: Yes, this is true, but it is explanatory as it currently stands. Further more, looking at the Execution plans, they are exactly the same.

Comment: -1 Not working correctly. Used your demo and changed the indata so group `A` and `B` should both be `F`. But thats not the case. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bd277/2